# Zurb Foundation leaving large gap to left of content

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation in a rails project. I'm trying to layout a simple page with a table, text field, and a couple of buttons.

There is a massive gap to the left of my content pushing the right side of the table off screen and requiring a horizontal scroll to see the content. The code is pretty simple. I create a twelve column row several times.

e.g.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <h1>Customers</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see a screenshot of the problem here. As you can see there is a lot of white space to the left of the table forcing the table past the right edge: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jd25l5epdn7ean5/Screenshot%202013-11-04%2011.29.31.png

I'm sure I'm making a simple mistake here but I just can't find it. This is my first time using Foundation - I usually use Bootstrap but thought I'd try something new on this project.

Update:

Full html:

```
   <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <h1>Customers</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <%= form_tag customers_path, :method => 'get' do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => "Enter last name..." %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => 'button small' %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>License #</th>
          <th>Date of birth</th>
          <th>Emergency Contact Name</th>
          <th>Emergency Contact #</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Registration Date</th>
          <th>Parent/Guardian?</th>
          <th>Guardian Tel Number</th>
          <th>Guardian License #</th>
          <th>Participant Signature</th>
          <th>Guardian Signature</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= customer.firstName %></td>
            <td><%= customer.last_name %></td>
            <td><%= customer.licenseNum %></td>
            <td><%= customer.dob %></td>
            <td><%= customer.contactName %></td>
            <td><%= customer.contactNum %></td>
            <td><%= customer.address %></td>
            <td><%= customer.city %></td>
            <td><%= customer.currentDate %></td>
            <td><%= customer.guardian %></td>
            <td><%= customer.guardianNum %></td>
            <td><%= customer.guardianLicenseNum %></td>
            <td><%= customer.participant_image_name %></td>
            <td><%- customer.guardian_image_name %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'View', customer, :class => 'button secondary' %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_customer_path(customer), :class => 'button secondary' %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Delete', customer, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this customer? This cannot be undone.' }, :class => 'button alert' %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <%= will_paginate @customers %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <%= link_to 'New Customer', new_customer_path, class: "button success"%>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will help if you make a jsfiddle with the full html code. Maybe you have a invisible sidebar or whatever.

Comment: @MurifoX I've added the full html above.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Foundation are you using? In Foundation 4, the markup should be:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-twelve small-twelve columns">
    <h1>Customers</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just changed it to that but still having the same problem.

Comment: It will be hard to diagnose your issue without seeing the whats actually going on on the live page. Can you post a link? In absence of that - did you use chrome dev tools, or firebug to inspect whats going on?